# Is there an easy explanation for the notion of Calderon projectors?

Tags: reference-request, pseudo-differential-operators

I recently stumbled upon the notion of Calderon projectors, which are standard tools for elliptic boundary value problems. However, when searching on the internet I could not really find any useful material that really explains the purpose of these operators. Usually, they just show a simple example and define them in this context but without interpretation.

Is there an easy way to explain what the purpose of these projectors is? And what are they projecting to?